# typo3 f:format.date hour and minutes are not displayed

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Hi I tried to print a datetime ... but hours and minutes are not printed.

Code looks like this:

```
        <span class="news-list-date meta-infos">
            <time datetime="{f:format.date(date:newsItem.datetime, format:'d-m-Y H:i')}">
                <f:format.date format="{f:translate(key:'dateFormat')}">{newsItem.datetime}</f:format.date>
                <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="{f:format.date(date:newsItem.datetime, format:'d-m-Y H:i')}"/>
            </time>
        </span>
```

Whats my fail?

thanks in advance

Comment: start with debugging what your translated time format is: `<f:debug title="tiem format">{f:translate(key:'dateFormat')}</f:debug>`. Then you need to identify where this string comes from (maybe multiple translation files are available, multiple languages with different translations?) does the output in general ignore hours and minutes? are the attributes from time- and meta-tag with minutes?

Comment: Try `<f:format.date format="d-m-Y - H:i">{newsItem.datetime}</f:format.date>` out **time** tag for check the correct configuration

Comment: that worked thanks! will you post it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:

`<f:format.date format="d-m-Y - H:i">{newsItem.datetime}</f:format.date>`

Thanks  César Dueñas

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the news `dateFormat` like below.

```
plugin.tx_news._LOCAL_LANG.default.dateFormat = d-m-Y H:i
```

Or

```
<f:format.date format="d-m-Y H:i">{newsItem.datetime}</f:format.date>
```

Comment: You can just add static dateFormat like **format = d-m-Y H:i** in <f:format.date tag and check the result. it's work or not?

Comment: **{f:translate(key:'dateFormat')}** is not correct in your template. so, mint and hours are not display

Answer (score 1):

You can change it with TypoScript, so you can provide different formats for each language. In the third line of your code you see, how it's done. You can use a snippet like this in your TS setup:

```
        # Modify the translation
_LOCAL_LANG {
    default {
        dateFormat = d-m-Y H:i
    }
         de {
        dateFormat = d-m-Y H:i 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with the language you use, e.g.:

```
plugin.tx_news._LOCAL_LANG.de.dateFormat = d-m-Y H:i
```

or

```
plugin.tx_news._LOCAL_LANG.en.dateFormat = d-m-Y H:i
```